# Is there a way to generate a set of maps at compile time in c++?

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism, c++17, c++14

I have an underlying function from another library as below -

```
template <typename K, typename V>
std::map<K,V> whatever(const int rc, const std::string& str) {
    return std::map<K,V>;
}
```

Now, my code wants to use this function whatever().

I've 3 sets of values each of my template arguments can have, namely int, double, and string.
These values come as input parameters to my application. I want to generate a map of all possible combinations on the fly i.e. at compile time. There are 9 possible scenarios that can be generated -

```
map<int, int>
map<int, double>
map<int, string>

map<double, int>
map<double, double>
map<double, string>

map<string, int>
map<string, double>
map<string, string>
```

The problem is essentially how to generate these 9 instances on the fly at compile-time since the templatized function accepts types, and input to my application is in form of enums.

```
0->int
1->string
2->double
```

The current most optimal solution I was able to come up with is to create 2 std::variants -

```
std::variant<9 possible maps> v1;

std::map<enum, std::variant>>  enumToVariant;
The std::variant in enumToVariant is of type std::variant<int, double, string>.
```

Following this, it is actually a one-liner using std::visit{overload} - which would visit both the respective variants and overload it with auto.

The problem with that method is it generates a single return type only. So it can only generate v1.
Source - https://www.cppstories.com/2018/09/visit-variants/

Is there a better way to do it? Or the approach I have is most optimal?

Comment: Can you show an example of how you want to use this? It's very hard to understand what you're actually trying to do in your question... This also looks like some [XY-problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: *"I want to generate a map of all possible combinations on the fly i.e. at compile time"* but you introduce enum too which seems runtime values... Could you provide sample code of expected usage?

Answer (score 0):

Not clear to me what do you want, exactly.

Anyway... I propose you a simple program that show you how to generate a `std::tuple` (the type only) containing all 9 `std::map` types.

```
#include <map>
#include <tuple>
#include <string>

template <typename T0, typename ... Ts>
auto gam_helper ()
{ return std::make_tuple(std::map<T0, Ts>{}...); }

template <typename ... Ts>
auto getAllMaps ()
{ return std::tuple_cat(gam_helper<Ts, Ts...>()...); }

int main ()
{
  using TX = decltype(getAllMaps<int, double, std::string>());
  using T0 = std::tuple_element<0u, TX>::type;
  using T1 = std::tuple_element<1u, TX>::type;
  using T2 = std::tuple_element<2u, TX>::type;
  using T3 = std::tuple_element<3u, TX>::type;
  using T4 = std::tuple_element<4u, TX>::type;
  using T5 = std::tuple_element<5u, TX>::type;
  using T6 = std::tuple_element<6u, TX>::type;
  using T7 = std::tuple_element<7u, TX>::type;
  using T8 = std::tuple_element<8u, TX>::type;


  static_assert( std::is_same_v<T0, std::map<int, int>>);
  static_assert( std::is_same_v<T1, std::map<int, double>>);
  static_assert( std::is_same_v<T2, std::map<int, std::string>>);
  static_assert( std::is_same_v<T3, std::map<double, int>>);
  static_assert( std::is_same_v<T4, std::map<double, double>>);
  static_assert( std::is_same_v<T5, std::map<double, std::string>>);
  static_assert( std::is_same_v<T6, std::map<std::string, int>>);
  static_assert( std::is_same_v<T7, std::map<std::string, double>>);
  static_assert( std::is_same_v<T8, std::map<std::string, std::string>>);
}
```